`extension FutureIterable<T>.wait` does not work properly in Dart/Flutter
extension FutureIterable<T>.wait does not work properly
from the documentation:
/// Similar to [Future.wait], but reports errors using a
/// [ParallelWaitError], which allows the caller to
/// handle errors and dispose successful results if necessary.

The following code:
Future<int> main() async {
  await process([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  return 0;
}

Future<void> process(Iterable<int> messages) async {
  print("len: ${messages.length}");
  Iterable<Future<int>> futures = messages.map((message) {
    return fibo(message);
  });
  assert(messages.length == futures.length);
  try {
    print("before big wait");
    await futures.wait;
    print("after big wait");
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.runtimeType);
    print("$e from the end");
  }
  print("stop!");
}

Future<int> fibo(int message) {
  throw "Test error handling";
}

output:
flutter: len: 5
flutter: before big wait
flutter: String
flutter: Test error handling from the end
flutter: stop!

I don't see any sign of ParallelWaitError, as the documentation mentions. And the future returns an error at the first exception.
What do I miss?

Instead of using throw, try using Future.error to return an error from your function:
Future<int> fibo(int message) {
  return Future.error("Test error handling");
}

The result will show the ParallelWaitError as you expect:
len: 5
before big wait
ParallelWaitError<List<int?>, List<AsyncError?>>
ParallelWaitError(5 errors): Test error handling from the end
stop!


Alternative, add the async keyword to the fibo function so it becomes an async function which will make it return async errors automatically.

You are right @julemand101, maybe that's even better.
